# Make each cell in row(1) in sheets(2) equal to each cell in column(A) in sheet(1) and make it loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
For Each cell In sheets(1).Range("A50:A606")
For Each cell2 In sheets(2).Range("EX2:ACB2")

   cell2.Value = cell.Value
Next
Next
```

(i know this is wrong but this is what i mean)

Answer (score 3):

Looping and using `Offset()`

```vb
Dim i As Long, cell As Range
For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("A50:A606")
    Sheets(2).Range("EX2").Offset(0, i).value = cell.value
    i = i + 1
Next
```

You can do it without a loop though using `Transpose()`:

```vb
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A50:A606")

Sheets(2).Range("EX2").Resize(rng.Columns.Count, rng.Rows.Count).Value = _
                                            Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
```